# How to calculate the sum of variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

It calculates, but starting from the second row.

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');
$query = "select * from users";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$sold= array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
  $sold=$row['contract']+$row['tva'];
  echo "<table><tr><td>" . $sold. "</td></tr></table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can we see a `var_dump` of the `result` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already extracted  a row from the result, with `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`, the script starts adding only with the next row. Th correct code would be:

```
 <?php
     include('connect-db.php');
    $query = "select * from users";
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    $sold= array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
    $sold=$row['contract']+$row['tva'];
    echo "<table><tr>
    <td>" . $sold. "</td>
    </tr></table>";
    }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thx a lot, great, it works,  i'm new in php, so stackoverflow it's very important for me. Thx and sorry if the question was stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many issues:

1. Your code starts to calculate from the second row because of the line:

   ```
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   ```

   which obtains the first result from the opened recordset before the `while` loop.
2. `$sold = array();`
   Why is that an array?

   If you want to sum to `$sold`, threat the variable as an integer and initialize it with a `0`.

   ```
   $sold = 0;
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     $sold += $row['contract']+$row['tva'];

   echo "<table><tr><td>" . $sold. "</td></tr></table>";
   ```

---

It seems to me also that you may want to print the table only once. If this is true, consider to query the database with an aggregation function like `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(contract + iva) AS contractIva FROM users GROUP BY <some column in your table>;
```

The above allows to remove the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that via query as well so that you don't need to perform calculation on the `application level`, `database level` can do this job for you.

```
 select sum(col1+col2) as total from users
```

And you want one table instead of multiple tables I guess, if yes then do it like this:

```
echo "<table>
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
   $sold=$row['contract']+$row['tva'];
  echo <tr><td>" . $sold. "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I was just about to post this myself, getting the database server to do it for you is the right way to do this.